# Unable to nslookup deployed nodes on maas server

Tags: networking, server, dns, maas

In the path toward establishment of an Openstack cloud I've already reach to the point that I must install juju and opensatck but the problem is a deployed node does not have access to the internet (which is strange since during the deployment process I certainly could see that it was getting things from the internet). Also on the maas server I couldn't nslookup, for example node01.maas (which is the name of deployed node) or its address 10.1.1.101, or even maas itself. When I nslookup maas.maas this is what I get:

```
ali@maas:~$ nslookup maas.maas
Server:         172.16.0.159
Address:        172.16.0.159#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   maas.maas
Address: 104.239.213.7
Name:   maas.maas
Address: 198.105.254.11
```

As you can see it shows some arbitrary addresses and it comes from the nameserver (172.16.0.159) which meant to handle public network not private one where nodes are laid on.
I've also followed some instructions for packet forwarding on maas server mentioned at lower part of this page: "http://www.openstackbasement.com/home/landscape-openstack-juju-won-t-bootstrap" to no avail. I dont know what else to do. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well after sometime finally one friend advised me to set up a NAT on maas through iptables rules which I did and that made the deployed nodes capable of accessing to the Internet through maas. Here is what I did exactly on the maas server:

```
iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface enp3s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp5s0 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
service iptables restart
```

All above from here "https://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables".
Then I did this command:

```
sudo iptables-save | sudo tee /etc/iptables.sav
```

And that was it, now nodes on the private network can get to the Internet. Still not able to nslookup their names neither on maas nor on nodes.

Time to go on to the next stage, installing Openstack & the burden of juju bootstrapping thing.